# Xcode notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, уведомления

Имеется будильник. Не могу сделать, чтобы при срабатывании будильника приходило уведомление. Нужно сделать push уведомление со звуком, пользователь должен ее отключать. 
Сейчас сделал просто notification уведомление.

Можно ли как-то сделать, используя notification то, о чем я написал выше?

```
    UILocalNotification * notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    notification.userInfo = dict;
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notification.fireDate = self.eventDate;
    notification.alertBody = _luck;
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notification.repeatInterval = 0;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NewEvent" object:nil];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: не совсем понятно, что именно вы хотите сделать. У вас есть нотификейшн. он должен показываться на экран в нужное время, и играть музыку (если телефон не в беззвучном режиме). А надо вам что?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Нужно, чтобы играла музыка до тех пор, пока пользователь не отключит ее. И в беззвучном режиме чтобы тоже работало. Это реально?

Comment: Вам надо в notification.soundName задать имя файла с музыкой, но мелодия должна быть более 30 секунд и каждые 30 секунд повторять notification. Второй вариант использовать AVAudioPlayer, указав категорию AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback. Что касается звука в режиме silent, не уверен, что нотификации позволяют это сделать.

Comment: как уже написали, можно играть мелодию каждые 30 секунд, и задать `setAction`, который будет всю это какофонию отменять (тогда на лок скрине появится кнопка). Отключенный звук на устройстве обойти не получится.

Answer (score 1):

В iOS8 и позже, ваше приложение должно запросить у пользователя разрешение на отправку уведомлений (даже локальных). Чтобы это сделать выполните следующий код до того, как вы делаете `scheduleLocalNotification`:

```
UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
         UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
```